# How do I compute all possible paths for the k-server using a dynamic programming solution?

Tags: c, algorithm, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming

Task Description:

You can ﬁnd the optimal strategy by a dynamic-programming type argument: If the input sequence was n request points long (p1,...,pn), you create an n × n × n × n array; the entry cost[i][j][k][t] is the cost of the cheapest sequence of moves that starts at the given starting positions and serves the requests up to time step t, and ends up with the yellow server at pi, the red server at pj, and the blue server at pk. One of ijk must be t, since the last request at pt was served, all other table entries have cost ∞. Any possible table entry must have been reached by moving one of the three servers from a position at step t − 1.

I am trying to compute all possible paths for the k-server dynamic programming solution when the number of servers is 3 but I keep getting incorrect values.

The is algorithm  is as follows:

```
cost[i][j][k][t] = min { min (cost[ m ][ j ][ k ][ t-1 ] + dist(m,i) for m=1..n ),
                         min (cost[ i ][ m ][ k ][ t-1 ] + dist(m,j) for m=1..n ), 
                         min (cost[ i ][ j ][ m ][ t-1 ] + dist(m,k) for m=1..n ) }
```

dist(m,i) is the distance between point m and point i

numReq is the number of requests points in the array requests

requests is the collection of all requests points with the position of server 1, 2, and 3 in index 0, 1, and 2 respectively. The array requests from index 3 to the end of the array are the positions of the request points that need to be served.

The Code:

```
for (int i=0; i<numReq; i++) {


    for (int j=0; j<numReq; j++) {


        for (int k=0; k<numReq; k++) {

            for(int t = 0; t<numReq; t++)
                cost[i][j][k][t] = 0;

        }
    }
}

for(int t=3; t<numReq; t++)
{
    for(int i=0; i<=t; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=t; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<=t; k++)
            {
                int current_min=INT_MAX;

                if((i!=t) && (j!=t) && (k!=t))
                    cost[i][j][k][t]=INT_MAX;
                else
                {
                    for(int m=0; m<=t; m++)
                    {
                        if(current_min > (cost[m][j][k][t-1] + findWeight(requests[m], requests[i])) && i>=3 && i!=m)
                        {
                            if(cost[m][j][k][t-1] + findWeight(requests[m], requests[i])>0){
                                current_min = cost[m][j][k][t-1] + findWeight(requests[m], requests[i]);

                            }

                        }
                    }

                    for(int m=0; m<=t; m++)
                    {
                        if(current_min > (cost[i][m][k][t-1] + findWeight(requests[m],requests[j])) &&j>=3 && j!=m)
                        {
                            if(cost[i][m][k][t-1] + findWeight(requests[m],requests[j])>0){
                                current_min = cost[i][m][k][t-1] + findWeight(requests[m],requests[j]);

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for(int m=0; m<=t; m++)
                    {
                        if(current_min > (cost[i][j][m][t-1] + findWeight(requests[m],requests[k])) &&k>=3 && k!=m)
                        {
                            if(cost[i][j][m][t-1] + findWeight(requests[m],requests[k])>0){
                                current_min = cost[i][j][m][t-1] + findWeight(requests[m],requests[k]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    cost[i][j][k][t] = current_min;
                    printf("Cost at %d,%d,%d,%d is: %d\n",i,j,k,t,cost[i][j][k][t]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the assist.

Comment: So what you're calling `l` in your code is what you call `t` in the problem and algorithm descriptions, yes?

Comment: You don't show any initialization or value assignment for elements of `total_cost` having fourth index 0, 1, or 2.  You need at least those with fourth index 2 for the computation of elements with fourth index 3, which in turn you need for the computation of subsequent values.

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect your remarks.

Comment: Supposing that the type of the elements of `cost` is `int`, computations of the form `current_min = cost[m][j][k][l-1] + findWeight(requests[m], requests[i]);` are problematic when `cost[m][j][k][l-1]` might be `INT_MAX`.  You will have integer overflows, which technically produce undefined behavior.  Practically, you're likely to see the resulting sum being a very negative integer, which will have a much different effect that you want.

Comment: Now that you've presented initialization for the first few hyperplanes of `cost`, I observe that many of those initial values do not satisfy the invariant described in the problem: " One of ijk must be t, since the last request at pt was served, all other table entries have cost ∞."

Comment: `if((i!=t) && (j!=t) && (k!=t))`
                    `cost[i][j][k][l]=INT_MAX;` That is what this code is for. To make sure i, j, or k is t

Comment: You are missing my point.  The line you reference is only executed for `t` at least 3.  Many of the array elements with smaller `t` do not satisfy the invariant.  Also, it looks like you've missed switching at least one `l` to a `t`.